# Django one-to-many relation: optimize code to reduce number of database queries executed

Tags: django, database, optimization, one-to-many

I have 2 models with a one-to-many relation on a MySQL DB:

```
class Domains(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Kpis(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    domain_id = models.ForeignKey(Domains, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='domain_id')
```

In order to bring ALL the domains with all their kpis objects, i use this code with a for loop:

```
final_list = []
domains_list = Domains.objects.all()
for domain in domains_list:
    # For each domain, get all related KPIs
    domain_kpis = domain.kpis_set.values()
    final_list.append({domain:domains_kpis})
```

The total number of queries i run is: 1 + the number of total domains i have, which is quite a lot.

I'm looking for a way to optimize this, preferably to execute it within only one query on the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for this:

```
final_list = []
domains_list = Domains.objects.prefetch_related('kpis_set')
for domain in domains_list:
    # For each domain, get all related KPIs
    domain_kpis = domain.kpis_set.all()
    final_list.append({domain:domains_kpis})
```

This will make two queries: one to query the domains, and a second to query all the related `Kpis` with a single query into memory.

Furthermore please do *not* use `.values()`. You can serialze data to JSON with Django's serializer framework, by making use of `.values()` you "erode" the model layer. See the [*Serializing Django objects* section of the documentation for more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/).

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. Can you please elaborate why the `.values()` method is not suggested? Does it increase the total execution time?

Comment: @shayms8: no it is a primitive obsession antipattern: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/over_use_of_values.html

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that you are asking a solution for "classic" N +1 queries problem. [Here](https://scoutapm.com/blog/django-and-the-n1-queries-problem) you can read a something about it and aslo find the examples for `prefetch_related` method adviced in Willem's answer.

Another thing worth mentioning is that probably you aren't suppose to use this dict `final_list.append({domain:domains_kpis})`, but instead you may want to map some field(s) from `Domain` to some field(s) from `Kapis` models and, if this is true, you can specify exact fields you'd like to have prefetched using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
domains_list = Domains.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('kpis_set'), queryset=Kapis.objects.all().only('some_field_you_want_to_have'))
final_list = []
for domain in domains_list:
    domain_kpis = domain.kpis_set.all()
    final_list.append({domain.some_field:domains_kpis.prefetched_field})
```

This should give another boost to performance on big-volume table's.